# How to assign values before unload event in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

Hi i want to assign two string values from popup window back to parent window which open the popup window.

for which i take two hidden field both in parent and child window as runat server,
and on button click event i assing these hidden field some text value

```
/*(Hidden field 1 ->)*/     c_value.Value = Treeview.SelectedNode.Parent.Value;
/*(Hidden field 2 ->)*/     c_text.Value = "File selected";
```

and on body unload event i assign these value to parent's hidden field through javascipt

(HTML)

```
<script>
  function assgin()
    {    

     window.opener.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_p_value").value = document.getElementById('c_value').value;

     window.opener.document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_p_text').value = document.getElementById('c_text').value;

</script>   

<body onunload="assign()">
```

but when i try to get these value on parent form it is showing empty.

i not understand why these values become empty may be due to onunload event, if this is the reason then tell me on which event i assign these values to parent form .i want to assign these values before closing child window.

Comment: Your JS function has a typo "assgin()" :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is due to a typo of "assgin()" function. But if not, here is a small example that works for me. NOTE: you can't test this on a local disk, because in that case the browser will prevent access to window.opener for security reasons.

parent.html

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.open('popup.html','My Popup')" value="Open popup" />
<br/>
Result from popup: <input type="text" id="result" />
```

popup.html

```
<script>
function assign() {
    window.opener.document.getElementById("result").value = document.getElementById("mystring").value;
}
</script>
<body onunload="assign()">
    Enter string and close the popup: <input type="text" id="mystring" />
<body>
```